# Display dropdown on hover

Tags: html, css

probably stupid question but:

I have a dropdown menu (ul) that is hidden by default (opacity: 0)
when a button at the same level is hovered, the ul gets opacity: 1.

**The problem is when the cursor leaves the button to select links in the menu, the menu disappears because the button is no longer hovered.**

nothing I googled helped me so I am asking here, thanks in advance.

btw I used opacity instead of display because I want simple delay (animation) when displaying the dropdown menu (transition: opacity .3 ease-in-out)

and I cannot use the hover on the whole parent element (div class="dropdown") since the ul has absolute position)

HTML

```
   <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn button--langs btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                                    Čeština
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                                    <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__list__item__link">English</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__list__item__link">Española</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown__list__item__link">Pусский</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

STYLES

```
        .dropdown

            &__list
                position: absolute
                padding: 0
                margin: 0
                list-style: none
                background-color: $trans-black
                transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out
                opacity: 0

                &__item

                    &__link
                        padding: .5rem .75rem
                        display: block
                        transition: .5s ease

                        &:hover
                            background-color: $black
                            text-decoration: none

            .button--langs:hover + .dropdown__list 
                opacity: 1
```

Comment: You'd need to add the hover handling to the dropdown as well. Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: First of all `opacity` should not be used to hide elements, as they are still clickable (when being invisible), you should use `display:none;` instead.

As for a button, just remove the `onmouseout` even't from the button.

Comment: one way would to be to put the dropdwon into your object, that gets opacity 1 and to add hover effect to it to

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the button and dropdown in one `div` and display dropdown on hover of that `div`.

If you can post your example code and expected output, it can be answered better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `display` attribute in CSS to set `display: none;` and on hover set `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

ok so the solution is to put the hover event on the list as well. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would attach the hover on *.dropdown* instead. You can't use `display: none` as mentioned in the comments, because that won't make the menu animate opacity. I therefor added `height: 0px` and `overflow:hidden` to your *.dropdown__list*, and set the height to `auto` when hovering the *.dropdown* element.

I changed the SASS to CSS in order to show the functionality.

```css
.dropdown {
  --color-black: #121212;

  /* ADDED */
  display: inline;
}

.dropdown__list {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: $trans-black;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;

  /* ADDED */
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* CHANGED */
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown__list {
  opacity: 1;

  /* ADDED */
  height: auto;
}

.dropdown__list__item__link {
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.dropdown__list__item__link:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-black);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn button--langs btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button">
        Čeština
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown__list">
        <li class="dropdown__list__item">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown__list__item__link">English</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__list__item">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown__list__item__link">Española</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown__list__item">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown__list__item__link">Pусский</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```